# OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS Requirement support

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Are there any changes needed to implement the requirements of HTTPS for FB apps?  Is there any documentation on what needs to happen?
More on the requirement  [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497)

Answer (score 0):

make sure to add "secureCanvasUrl" in web.config and also make sure your site is being served in https protocol.